# Bash Iterate loop inside list

Tags: bash, list, loops

I have a list of servers where I need to perform series of similar commands on each. Script takes information about commands from external file. Server`s list hardcoded into script itself. 
For this purposes I created a script. Unfortunate, it goes through server's list and takes only first line from input.txt

```
declare ip_array=( xxx.xxx.xx.xx yyy.yyy.yy.yy zzz.zzz.zz.zz )  

for ADDM_address in "${ip_array[@]}"; do

while IFS= read -r snmp_cred; do


    snmp_ip=$(grep -E -o "blabla" <<< $snmp_cred)
    snmp_ip=${snmp_ip%?}


   $perform some commands



done </tmp/input.txt


done
```

---

Content of input.txt file:

```
h3c/sseries/1.3.6.1.4.1.25506.11.1.99_hp_a3100_48_v2/172.30.152.20@public
h3c/sseries/1.3.6.1.4.1.25506.11.1.9_hp_v1905_24_poe/10.159.2.31@public
a10networks/generic/1.3.6.1.4.1.22610.1.3.16_ax3200_12/10.251.1.101@public
```

---

Can you help me to construct proper loop, so it goes through all content of input.txt file, non only through first element.

The output in terminal is:

http://prnt.sc/ceg27j

Comment: At the moment, I can't see any major issues with your script. Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, Tom! I have added screenshot with verbose output from terminal.

Comment: How are the entries in `input.txt` separated?

Comment: As a new lines. Here is testing input.txt file - http://www.filedropper.com/input_3

Comment: If "perform some commands" consumes your stdin, that's the culprit.

Comment: </dev/null helped me as well! Thanks @triplee